# Height looks different in Chrome / Firefox / Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My code is perfect for Chrome, but not for others ..
Look at pictures, the  parent of ul has a margin-top to his child (ul). It's working fine for Chrome, but for others it's too much !

Chrome (it's ok)
[image]

Firefox and Safari (not ok)
[image]

I'm not using webkit or moz, nor transition or other property like that.

**EDIT**

Sorry I forgotten the code ^^
The ul is in .wrap-orange-notre-vision :

```
#section-notre-vision:before{
  content: "UNE OFFRE QUI MODERNISE ET AMÉLIORE VOTRE RELATION CLIENT.";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto !important;
}
section#section-notre-vision{
    height: 555px;
    min-height: 500px;
}

.wrap-orange-notre-vision{
    margin-top: 925px;
}
```

**EDIT**

It was just due to WordPress

Comment: You may have to share some of your CSS/HTML in order for people to help you - it's hard to tell what's wrong just from a screenshot.

Comment: Post your code or an isolated example fiddle. I bet you'll fix it yourself in the process of isolating the example though.

Comment: well. without any relevant code we cannot help you :)

Comment: Please also include the HTML code to go with it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure each browser renders html and css slightly differently due to some specs in the browsers code. I cant remember exactly what the difference is, but i know that there is a small difference.